# How to correctly use <svg> tags with jquery in intellij?

Tags: html, jquery, jsbarcode

So here I have CDN of both JQuery & jsbarcode -> jsbarcode info https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/
The output should show a barcode the the const "number" var.

```html
  

    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"  >

    </head>
    <body >
  
    </div>

         <script>
            const number = '12345678';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                JsBarcode("#barcode", number, {
                    text: number.match(/.{1,4}/g).join("  "),
                    width: 2,
                    height: 50,
                    fontSize: 15,
                });
            });
        </script>

        <svg id="barcode"></svg>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>



    </body>



</html>
```

Comment: Two things:  1)  Pleas [edit] your question to add what you are seeing when you view the web page. 2) Click on the "Run code snippet" button and look at the error message that appears, and see if fixing that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the script tags for your libraries before the code that uses them. They can go within the `<head>` tag. Your code snippet becomes the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  const number = '12345678';
  $(document).ready(function(){
      JsBarcode("#barcode", number, {
          text: number.match(/.{1,4}/g).join("  "),
          width: 2,
          height: 50,
          fontSize: 15,
      });
  });
</script>
<svg id="barcode"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

(In the code snippet I provided I also cleaned up some errors in the HTML, like the `</div>` for a nonexistent `div` tag.)

Comment: for some reason its blank, doesnt seem to be showing anything.

Comment: I just ran it directly from my answer and it works. It does take about a second to load, but other than that I'm  not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just realized that one of my css classes was interfering with it. This works perfectly. Thank you